# Can't register for push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification

So while registering for push notifications with

```
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

I get no alert for the user to accept it and the app does not show in notification center. I tried all the solutions posted in previous topics, I implemented the

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
```

However that does not get called ever, it seems as if the whole registering is completely ignored. I am using an iPad to debug, have Development Provisioning profiles and certificates.

Comment: Are you sure push notifications are enabled on your provisioning profile?

Comment: what is the log message in console when registerForRemoteNotificationTypes is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect APNS is not enabled on your `provisioning profile(sample.mobileprovision)`.

Open your provisioning profile in `TextEdit` and search for `aps-environment` key in the opened text file.

If you don't find, then APNS is not enabled.